# HTML input pattern not working validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have very strange issue.

in a very sample search form with one input field:

```html
 <input pattern="\S.{3,}"  name="text"/>
```

The validation fails for value

```
     dds sdsd
```

, but JS says it's Ok.

```js
/\S.{3,}/.test('     dds sdsd')
true
/\S.{3,}/.test('    ')
false
```

Maybe I am missing something small or pattern is wrong, but according to regex.com it should be valid.
The idea is to prevent submit empty spaces. I am searching for a solution without write JS code.

```html
<form method="GET" action="/">
<input class="form-control" name="text" type="text" pattern="\S.{3,}"  />
<input type="submit" value="search" >
</form>
```

Comment: you have a typo error in your first example (parttern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTML5 `pattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) is anchored by default, `^(?:` and `)$` are added at the start/end of the pattern when it is passed JS regex engine.

You need to use

```
<input pattern=".*\S.{3,}.*"  name="text"/>
```

to make it work the same way as in JS with `RegExp#test`.

However, to require at least 1 non-whitespace char in the input, I'd recommend using

```
<input pattern="\s*\S.*"  name="text"/>
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aomHbQ/1). It will match 0+ whitespace chars at the start of the string (`\s*`), then will match any non-whitespace char (`\S`) and then will grab any 0+ chars greedily up to the end of the input.

```html
<form method="GET" action="/">
<input class="form-control" name="text" type="text" pattern="\s*\S.*" title="No whitespace-only input allowed."/>
<input type="submit" value="search" >
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks `.*\S.{3,}.*` does the trick .  My target is to have at least 3 symbols in the input

Comment: Any 3 symbols? Or 3 consecutive non-whitespace symbols? Or 3 non-whitespace symbols anywhere in the string? Please let know of actual requirements, since `\S.{3,}` looks strange: a non-whitespace char followed with any 3 or more chars.

Comment: Yeah it's strange. If I have leading spaces but there are `'    a a'` in the string it should match. I mean something like trim start and end. The best for now is `.*\S.{1,}\S`

Comment: Ok, if you plan to require at least  3 non-whitespace symbols, use [`pattern="(?:\s*\S){3}.*"`](https://regex101.com/r/jtZQkW/2). To match at least 3 consecutive non-whitespace symbols in  a string, use `pattern=".*\S{3}.*"`. Feel free to drop a comment in case you need more help with it.

Comment: The space between letters is correct. Only spaces at the start and the end should be ignored. I think, the pattern from previous comment works. Thanks for the help